# How do I trace CEP processing in WSO2 CEP?

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing

I am attempting to emulate the Build Analyzer example with my own bucket and input stream. I believe I have set up everything correctly, but when I run test data, I do not get any results.

The entire log output is

[2013-03-29 08:57:16,988]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.DataBridge} -  admin connected

Of course this makes sense when running in a production environment, but I have not been able to figure out how to increase the log level, ideally to some sort of trace mode, so I can see what is going on.

There are plenty of places to increase log levels, but unless I know which log levels to increase, I am afraid all I will do is add noise. How do I turn on appropriate logging in order to figure out what is going on?

As an aside, in my ideal world, there would be a place in the admin console where 1) all the streams and processes are mapped out (and verified) and 2) it would be possible to check a box to start tracing any stream.

TIA,

doug

Answer (score 0):

The Build Analyser example is basically related to REST transport and email broker. The result of the example is an e-mail to a email account which you provide in the bucket configuration. To see the stream definitions you can go through the registry which is given in the management console of the CEP. We have given a graphical window to see the the events which are coming to CEP, In [1] of our documentation gives details about this. (To see the events graphically manner you must have proper input mapping for the bucket.

Yes I agree with you regarding logging. We are working on CEP to provide more user-friendliness to user in our future releases. Thank you for your thoughts and we'll take those in to our consideration.

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/CEP210/CEP+Server+Statistics

Cheers,

Mohan